# What is 'File System' partition and how to free space on it?

Tags: linux-mint, partition

There's `File System` and there's `Home` in My Computer on Linux Mint. I understand that File System holds system files etc., home is for personalised data. What gets me is that when I open File System there's home folder - which is at the same time a separate partition. Is it just a link? I need to free space from File System and don't really know emptying which folders within File System would do the job.

[image]

Comment: No, that File System means / directory, Home means $HOME directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *File System* directory, usually referred to as *root* (`/`) directory, is the directory which contains all other directories in your system, as shown in the following image.

[image: root directory structure]

Your *Home* directory is a directory inside `/`. Specifically, it's the `/home/<your username>/` directory. You can read more about the Linux file system [here](https://thesagediary.com/2018/09/26/linux-file-system-directory-architecture/).

If you want to use another partition as your *Home*, you can `mount` the partition to `/home/<your username>/` by editing the `/etc/fstab` file. Usually you don't have to edit this file manually, since you select your `/home` during the OS installation (see image below).

[image: set home during installation]

Generally speaking, mounting a partition is similar to creating a symbolic link, not to a file or directory, but to a disk partition.

As for the last part of your question, it is **very dangerous** to delete files and folders outside your *Home*, unless you really know what you're doing. The recommended way to free up some space on your *File System* is to delete the programs that you don't need, using the tools of your OS, like `apt`, `apt-get`, etc. Other than that, if you need more space for the *File System* you could resize the `/` partition, but this depends on your partitions' configuration and is not always easy to do.

Comment: Thank you. Mounting a partition to home explains a lot.  I ended up removing some old kernels and unused software.

Answer (score 1):

A more technically accurate name for what they are calling “file system” would be “file hierarchy.”

If you read the man page about path resolution (section 7 of the man pages), it refers only to “file hierarchy” because it’s irrelevant what filesystem the files are stored in—all files on one computer appear in the one single file hierarchy (which can have multiple filesystems mounted into it).

Filesystems and partitions are both concepts that are usually abstracted away from the user (though I haven’t used Mint so can’t speak to its user experience specifically).

Your file hierarchy *includes* your home directory, as well as the directory called “home” (which contains your home directory, which is named with your user name).  Your file hierarchy includes everything.

Generally speaking, as a typical user (not an administrator) you shouldn’t need to directly handle files outside of your home directory very often.  This is probably what gives you the idea that “File System” contains system files.  Really it contains *everything*, but since you have other shortcuts to the stuff in your home directory, you would mostly only go to “File System” when you want to get to system files.

Don’t go deleting system files.  You can bork your whole computer that way unless you know exactly what you’re doing.  Start by finding out what is taking up the most space; some likely culprits are video files and photos, or music, or large software packages (some of which you may not be using).

(Mostly I am addressing the first half of your title question, with only a short bit on the second.)